# Android OpenGL - glTranslatef is retained after glPopMatrix

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, translate

With my sprites in my game I am drawing them by looping through each sprite, calling glPushMatrix, transforming to position, drawing the quad and calling glPopMatrix.

I would expect this to be fine, but I'm getting some odd behavior, some other objects on the screen are (seemingly) randomly translated some amount. I think somehow the transform for the position of the sprite is effecting the other drawing, but how could that happen after calling glPopMatrix?

I am drawing sprites and points, for some reason when I just draw points nothing gets this random translation. When I start drawing sprites it occurs, can anyone help work out what is causing it?

Here is my drawing routine for sprites:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();

//set the drawing position
gl.glTranslatef((float)positionDelta.getX(), (float)positionDelta.getY(), z);
gl.glRotatef((float) (180*angle/Math.PI), 0, 0, 1);

//draw 
getSprite().draw(gl);

//reset the drawing position
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

and the drawing function for the quad:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  //Bind our only previously generated texture in this case
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getGLID());

  //Point to our buffers
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  //Set the face rotation
  gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

  //Enable the vertex and texture state
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

  //Set The Color To Blue
  gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   

  //Draw the vertices as triangles, based on the Index Buffer information
  gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);      


  //Disable the client state before leaving
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

here is the drawing for something that always seems to get translated, a simple point:

```
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Point to our buffers
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

//Set the face rotation
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

//Enable the vertex and texture state
//gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

gl.glPushMatrix();

//set the drawing position
gl.glTranslatef((float)positionDelta.getX(), (float)positionDelta.getY(), z);

gl.glPointSize(size);

gl.glColor4f(red, green, blue, alpha);

//Draw the vertices as triangles, based on the Index Buffer information
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_POINTS, indexBuffer.capacity(), GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);

//Disable the client state before leaving
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

//reset the drawing position
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

(for comments below) OnSurfaceChange:

```
     @Override
  public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 60.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -width, width , -height, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    //font loading stuff
    texFont = new TexFont(context, gl);
    try {
      getTexFont().LoadFont("Fonts/Palatino Linotype.bff", gl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Here are a section of the OpenGL calls:

```
04-01 13:46:08.535: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glPushMatrix();
04-01 13:46:08.535: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glTranslatef(15.63553, 119.22188, 0.0);
04-01 13:46:08.540: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glRotatef(61.17992, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
04-01 13:46:08.540: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
04-01 13:46:08.540: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
04-01 13:46:08.540: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
04-01 13:46:08.540: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
04-01 13:46:08.545: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glFrontFace(2305);
04-01 13:46:08.545: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, java.nio.FloatToByteBufferAdapter, status: capacity=12 position=0 limit=12);
04-01 13:46:08.545: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, java.nio.FloatToByteBufferAdapter, status: capacity=8 position=0 limit=8);
04-01 13:46:08.565: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [0 : 0] = v:{-40.0, -40.0, 0.0} t:{0.0, 0.0}
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [1 : 1] = v:{40.0, -40.0, 0.0} t:{0.0, 1.0}
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [2 : 3] = v:{40.0, 40.0, 0.0} t:{1.0, 1.0}
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [3 : 0] = v:{-40.0, -40.0, 0.0} t:{0.0, 0.0}
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [4 : 3] = v:{40.0, 40.0, 0.0} t:{1.0, 1.0}
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [5 : 2] = v:{-40.0, 40.0, 0.0} t:{1.0, 0.0}
04-01 13:46:08.580: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): );
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glPopMatrix();
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glFrontFace(2305);
04-01 13:46:08.590: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glPushMatrix();
04-01 13:46:08.595: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glTranslatef(-14.2896805, 191.06998, 0.0);
04-01 13:46:08.595: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glPointSize(5.0);
04-01 13:46:08.595: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
04-01 13:46:08.600: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
04-01 13:46:08.600: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649):  [0 : 0] = v:{-40.0, -40.0, 0.0}
04-01 13:46:08.600: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): );
04-01 13:46:08.600: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
04-01 13:46:08.600: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(20649): glPopMatrix();
```

Its drawing some points, followed by a sprite, followed by some points again. Everything looks fine, except I noticed the vertices for the points is -40, -40. I don't think its a coincidence that that happens to be the same as the first vertex of the quad! It would seem that this is the issue, rather than with the matrix.

**edit** Found it!

```
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
```

was missing for the points, which meant they used the first vertex of the last drawn object, which if it was a sprite was -40,-40! Thanks!

Comment: There's no call to `glMatrixMode` anywhere - you sure this is correct?

Comment: there is during onSurfaceChanged

I call
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION) gl.glLoadIdentity() then gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW) 
    gl.glLoadIdentity()

Comment: cant put code here, added onSurfaceChange to end of question. Do I have it in the wrong place?

Comment: Looks OK, as long as this is the only position where the switch is done. Since you're using GL10, set the [DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS) via [setDebugFlags][1]. This wraps the GL10 instance and makes the calls appear in LogCat (footnote: I hope the push/pop calls are included, this doesn't work for GLES20). Sprinkle in some log calls yourself as _markers_ inside the log stream.

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setDebugFlags(int)

Comment: _Sorry, I could not correct the last link; somehow, MarkDown does not like closing parenthesis at a link's end_

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that led me right to the problem. I don't know how to give reputation for a comment!

Comment: Good to hear that! I have copypasted the comment as an answer, please accept. If possible, comment the answer briefly s.t. other people can profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK, as long as this is the only position where the switch is done. Since you're using GL10, set the [DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS) via [setDebugFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setDebugFlags%28int%29). This wraps the GL10 instance and makes the calls appear in LogCat (footnote: I hope the push/pop calls are included, this doesn't work for GLES20). Sprinkle in some log calls yourself as markers inside the log stream.